# how to use incremental build in Gatsby feature without Gatsby cloud

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, vercel, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-cloud

I am using Gatsby version "2.32.13" in my website and now I want to use Gatsby Incremental Build feature for my website but as my website is hosted on vercel I do not want to go for Gatsby Cloud.
So what are the ways to implement this Gatsby Incremental Build feature without use of Gatsby Cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work on any CI/CD platform (Netlify, Vercel, etc) even in Gatsby Cloud the implementation is far way easier. You only need to tweak your deploy command by adding the environment variable `GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES`. Like:

```
GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true gatsby build --log-pages
```

*Note: the `--log-pages` flag will help you to identify the built pages on each run*

To ensure a cross-environment command support I'd recommend installing [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) dependency and tweaking the previous command accordingly:

```
cross-env GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true gatsby build --log-pages
```

To give a [full (and official from Gatsby team)](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26741#issuecomment-685416917) explanation about the caveats:

> Conditional Page builds is an experimental feature that only works
> with data updates. Data updates in Gatsby means, data that comes from
> the GraphQL layer, in this case only page queries are supported. It
> can work with JSON updates when using `gatsby-transformer-json` and
> `gatsby-source-filesystem`.
>
> Gatsby at this point in time is not going to invest in this feature
> and it will probably stay experimental without any development.
>
> For more info about our roadmap see
> https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/announcing-unified-gatsby

Comment: I have added this environment variable **GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true**  in my Vercel environemnt  varaible setting but how shall I use it inside my code to do the work

Comment: You don't need to use it in your code. It's a CI tool (DevOps), not a React one. You just need to deploy your site and the CI will (or should) do the rest